Taking Dante to the submarine
I'm looking for a movie that I've seen on TV around 2000. There is some kind of catastrophic event ongoing (not sure if local or global) and people are being evacuated by submarine.
During the inspection of luggage while being granted a place in a sub, a wealthy man is being forced to get rid of a copy of The Divine Comedy from his suitcase to save space. He then screams that this is a print in original old Italian and if anything from the old world should remain after the catastrophe, then it should be this book.
That one scene survived in my childhood memories and made me interested in Dante as an adult, which was a starting point for great adventure around that topic. I'm a big fan now, have read it in few translations to my language. And the only thing I'm missing is that initial impulse.
Do you have any suggestions what could that movie be?

Was the movie color or black and white? You might also review Tips for asking Movie/TV Identification questions

After some extensive searching I cannot find any reference to this which matches all of the details you mention.
However, have you considered that your details may be fuzzy, and you're actually remembering The Day After Tomorrow?

It's a global disaster movie
It's an early 2000s movie (2004)
New York is flooding while the characters take refuge in the NY library, trapped inside with no way to escape
Not a submarine, but at some point a large ship travels through the flooded NY streets, passing by the library (and stranding itself close to it)
There is a character specifically choosing to save one book, due to its literary importance, in the face of the end of civilization as we know it

Script excerpt:

Elsa: What've you got there?
Jeremy: The Gutenberg Bible. It was in the Rare Books Room.
Elsa: Think God's gonna save you?
Jeremy: No. I don't believe in God.
Elsa: You're holding on to that Bible pretty tight.
Jeremy: I'm protecting it.
[pause as Elsa glances at J.D. throwing books on the fire]
Jeremy: This Bible... is the first book ever printed. It represents... the dawn of the Age of Reason. As far as I'm concerned, the written word is mankind's greatest achievement.
[Elsa gives a light snort]
Jeremy: You can laugh... but if Western civilization is finished... I'm gonna' save at least one little piece of it.


The one match missing from the above suggestion is this:

During the inspection of luggage while being granted a place in a sub, a wealthy man is being forced to get rid of a copy of The Divine Comedy from his suitcase to save space.

In the theme of disaster movies, 2012 comes to mind.

It's a disaster movie (albeit released in 2009, not 2000s)
The main character is an author, and will carry their book around for the entire movie, including reading it on the rescue ship (see script below)
It features scenes of people queueing to get aboard a ship (not specifically a submarine but they are very similar looking, see picture below) and having to give up possessions in the process.
Only the obscenely wealthy are afforded a place on this ship, with the exception of the protagonist and their family (i.e. they're not rich, they just show up on time and have plot armor)




A lot of what you say matches these movies... except The Divine Comedy. Wikipedia has an extensive list of references to The Divine Comedy in film, and none seem to match your description, content and timeline.

I'm wondering if it was localised into different books for different dubs

You should probably separate this into 2 different answers so that falt8 could pick one if it is correct.

both descriptions of the atmosphere match what I remember from that movie, but one thing I'm sure was the presence of "The Divine Comedy". I've seen it on TV in Poland, so I highly doubt that it had beed mixed with the Bible. thank you! I've seen both above movies in the past, but will rewatch them to see if anything clicks

@falt8: Do the Polish dub or sub their English movies? For The Day After Tomorrow, it never looks like a bible (just a brown leatherbound book) so Valorum might be right that they may have dubbed/subbed the name of the book to something different.

@Valorum Even subs would apply here, because the Gutenberg bible in TDAT is never really shown (it's just some indiscriminate brown leatherbound book).

@ArlettaS: If I'm on the right track I get the feeling that OP has conflated these two movies, rather than it being one or the other. The submarine callout is a very specific one, but so is the "save a book" scene, and these are split across two movies that are thematically similar in that they deal with a doomsday scenario (both flooding, and both containing general apocalyptic disasters).

@Flater "Do the Polish dub or sub their English movies?" Not that it matters for answering the question, but we do neither. You might be surprised.
